# Node.js fs.readFile()

Tags: node.js

can anyone think of a reason for the readFile function's callback doesn't get executed?

```
fs.exists(filePath, function(exists){
   if(exists){ // results true
      fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8", function(err, data){
         if(err){
            console.log(err)
         }              
         console.log(data);
      })
   }
});
```

filePath is ./etc/coords.txt and it's a json formatted string.

using the Sync version - readFileSync - doesn't work as well.

Comment: As stated by the documentation, "checking if a file exists before opening it is an anti-pattern that leaves you vulnerable to race conditions" because the file can be removed between the `exists` and `readFile` calls. To avoid this, check if `err.code === ENOENT` in the read callback for if a file exists or not.

Answer (score 10):

Because the options is an object not a string:

> #### fs.readFile(filename, [options], callback)
>
> - `filename` String
> - `options` Object
>
>   - `encoding` String | Null default = null
>   - `flag` String default = 'r'
> - `callback` Function
>
> Asynchronously reads the entire contents of a file. Example:
>
> ```
> fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', function (err, data) {   
>     if (err) throw err;   console.log(data); 
>   });
> ```
>
> The callback is passed two arguments (err, data), where data is the
>   contents of the file.

So:

```
fs.exists(filePath, function(exists){
   if(exists){ // results true
      fs.readFile(filePath, {encoding: "utf8"}, function(err, data){
         if(err){
            console.log(err)
         }              
         console.log(data);
      })
   }
});
```

Comment: Protip regarding the `encoding` option: _If `options` is a string, then it specifies the encoding. Example:_

`fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', 'utf8', callback);` (from the `Node.js` documentation)

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be related to a problem with the text file.
This file was generated by a C# app that wrote to the file a stream that contains Environment.NewLine
Not sure that's it, anyway, once I have removed to Environment.NewLine it worked.

Answer (score 0):

if its found locally just use
var contents = require("./file.txt");